# Display emails from specific sender as "Simple HTML"

Tags: html, email, thunderbird

I prefer to read my emails in Thunderbird as plain text, and when I get an email which doesn’t contain a plain text variant, I switch to "Simple HTML" or "Original HTML" by going to <kbd>View</kbd> → <kbd>Message Body As</kbd>, and switch back after reading it. As this happens rarely, I’m fine with this workflow.

But now I’m getting HTML-only mails from a specific sender each day, and it’s too bothersome to manually switch to HTML and back to plain text.

I read about the add-on [Allow HTML Temp](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/allow-html-temp/), that adds a button to the toolbar which switches to HTML for the current message. While this would be a good improvement, I wonder if there’s an even better solution for me:

- Let me specify criteria for incoming emails, similar to the Filter options (e.g.: email addresses in TO, CC, FROM; beginning of subject line; etc.), and
- let me select a display mode if the criteria match ("Simple HTML" or "Original HTML").

(**tl;dr**) So I could specify that all emails from our-emails-suck@example.com should be displayed as "Simple HTML".